# Export iTunes library?

Tags: itunes, export, applescript

A long time ago, I remember using an AppleScript I downloaded from somewhere that exports all the music files from my iTunes library into folder neatly organised by artist and albums.

Now, I am running iTunes 12.3.2.35 on Mac OS X 10.9.5, and would like to do he same thing again. Does anyone know if such a script exists for iTunes now, or if there is another way to export all files my entire iTunes library? Thank you.

Comment: On Windows, all the music is stored in `<HOME FOLDER>\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music` by default.  It's organized by `Artist\Album\music.m4a`. You can also see what folder it is in by going to `Preferences->Advanced`, and it will show you the iTunes Media folder location, which you can change.  I'm not sure if this works on OS X, which is why this is a comment, but on Windows iTunes ver. 12.3.2.35,  you can just copy the Music folder to wherever you want it; it's already organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view and change your iTunes Media folder location in `Preferences->Advanced`. If you downloaded the music, you can copy the Music folder in this place to wherever you want.  It should already be organized in folders by Artist/Album/musics.

Also, from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204668:

> Make sure that you're in Finder. From the menu bar at the top of your computer screen, choose Go > Home > Music > iTunes.